# Assume that $f:(0,∞)→ℝ$ is twice differentiable with $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in (0, ∞)$. Prove that $f''(x)$ cannot always be negative.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Assume that $f:(0,∞)→ℝ$ is twice differentiable with $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in (0, ∞)$. Prove that $f''(x)$ cannot always be negative.

I know that it intuitively makes sense because if $f$ is always decreasing with a positive derivative, then at some point, it must be concave up. However, I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = f'(1)$ and $b = f(1)$. Then we have $a < 0 < b$. Now assume $f''(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$. That means that $f'(x) \leq a$ for all $x > 1$, which again means that $f(x) \leq ax + b - a$ for all $x \geq 1$. Inserting some $x > \frac{a-b}{a}$ contradicts $f(x) > 0$.

Comment: $a$ has to be negative according to the assumptions. It also has to be negative for this argument to work I think?

Comment: @K.Power You're right. I mixed up $a$ and $b$ in that first inequality.

Comment: I suspected as much. +1 for a succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this is the following. $f$ is a positive strictly decreasing function on $(0, +\infty)$. Therefore the limit of $f(x)$ for $x \to +\infty$ exists and it is finite (in particular non-negative).

Now, if $f''(x)$ was alays negative, then $f$ would be strictly concave on $(0,+\infty)$ and the limit of $f(x)$ for $x\to+\infty$ would be $-\infty$, which is a contraddiction.